# Nginx as http proxy in two different networks and must use udp

Tags: nginx

I face a challenge, nginx as http proxy in two different networks and must use udp. There are some conditions:

1. Two different networks: A network and B network, they can't connect directly.
2. One proxy server that only support udp: udp-proxy-server, this server have two network interface cards that one is A network and another is B network.
3. Data transfer to A network udp-17002(port) will transfer to B network udp-30001(port) by the udp-proxy-server.

The final target is: client like phone in A network that can call service api successly in B network .

I found that http3 use the udp as the bottom protocol, so I build the nginx that support http3 by the quiche(https://github.com/cloudflare/quiche). I want use the http3 nginx as proxy server and proxy client.

[my-process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4FBN.png)

Now, I stay in the first step, I don't know how to convert http1.1 request to http3, Do you have any good ideas about it?

Comment: "HTTP/3 is the third and recently standardized major version of HTTP. HTTP/3 uses the same semantics as HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2: the same request methods, status codes, and message fields apply to all versions. The differences are in the underlying transport. Both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 use TCP as their transport. HTTP/3 uses a transport technology developed alongside HTTP/3 called QUIC." (source: [Use HTTP/3 with HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-http3)), so nginx should convert that transparently for you when it supports it, and when config is ok.

Comment: This is a badly explained ,confusing description of a somewhat arbitrary set of constraints. Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Sorry about my explaination. To be honest, this is my first question, i lost to many detail. 
Fortunately, I completed it. I use the kwik(QUIC in Java) to transfer HTTP in UDP. Using a HttpServer to receive http1 request, and transfer it to http3 by kwik-client. In kwik-server, I receive http3 request form kwik-client and call it to my application by http1. In my understanding, it's a http to udp proxy.